# How to save as an XML file directly from the database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, xml, rss

Currently, I have RSS/XML feeds written to the database, but I want to make these publicly accessible.

For example, for Module A, I would like it so you could go to feed.php?module=A and it would generate a feed with a .xml file-ending, e.g. feed.xml.

Example XML code from database:

```
[?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?]
[rss version="2.0"]
[channel]
[title]Module news for module A: D&D[/title]
[description]Desc for module here[/description]
[language]en[/language]
[item]
[title]test article[/title]
[pubDate]Tue, 20 Sep 2011 16:14:20[/pubDate]
[description]A test article would go here.[/description]
[link]http://www.google.com[/link]
[author]esujdt[/author]
[guid]http://www.google.com[/guid]
[/item]
[/channel]
[/rss]
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: That's not XML... close though :P

Comment: why does it have square brackets? Also, what is the problem? If the XML is already in the database, you can simply serve it with an application/xml header to the end user? Please clarify what exactly you need help with.

Comment: See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/xml-functions.html

Comment: Oops forgot to change those back before pasting, they're square as it's being included in an xml file elsewhere...long story, I'm not the person working on that bit. They will be angled in my feed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just issue a header() to specify content-disposition, which lets you provide a filename:

```
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=feed.xml');
header('Content-type: text/xml');
header('Content-length: ' . strlen($xml));
echo $xml;
```

Comment: That should be `application/rss+xml`